# How to Call External API with x-api-key in headers from spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, http-headers, api-key

I am trying to call an external api with **x-api-key** in **headers** from my spring boot application and ended up with following exception.

2022-01-22 22:44:19.973 ERROR 8828 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$Forbidden: 403 Forbidden: "{"message":"Forbidden"}"] with root cause

org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$Forbidden: 403 Forbidden: "{"message":"Forbidden"}"
at org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException.create(HttpClientErrorException.java:109) ~[spring-web-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:168) ~[spring-web-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:122) ~[spring-web-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
at org.springframework.web.client.ResponseErrorHandler.handleError(ResponseErrorHandler.java:63) ~[spring-web-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:819) ~[spring-

**My Controller looks like below:**

```
 @RestController
    @RequestMapping("/callExternalApi")
    public class ExternalApiCallerController {
        
        @PostMapping
        @ResponseBody
        public ResponseEntity<String> callExternalApi(@RequestBody String url) {
            Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
            headers.put("x-api-key", "Hnmn1nhsg7wbkItsAdv");
            HttpEntity<Object> entity=new HttpEntity<Object>(headers);
    
            RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
            ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class);
            
            return response;
        }
    
    }
```

It looks like the x-api-key is not sent in headers correctly to the external api. Can anyone please help how to call external api with x-api-key in headers?

Answer (score 5):

This code worked for me. HttpHeaders object needs to be used to add x-api-key and it's value.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/callExternalApi")
public class ExternalApiCallerController {

    @PostMapping
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<String> callExternalApi(@RequestBody String url) {
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.add("x-api-key", "Hnmn1nhsg7wbkItsAdv");
        HttpEntity<Object> entity=new HttpEntity<Object>(headers);

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class);

        return response;
    }

}
```